# How to mock super.method using PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit, powermock, powermockito

How to mock super class method using power mock. In CardRepo in am using superclass method to get jdbcTemplate but using power mock i am not able to mock super.method in CardRepo class. how to mock super.getJdbcTemplate() using power mock.

```
public abstract class AbstractRepository {
    @Autowire
    private static JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
Class CardRepo extends AbstractRepository{
    @Override
    public List<Card> getCardList(CommonInputBean inputBean) {
        List<Card> data=Collections.emptyList();
        data = super.getJdbcTemplate().query(query.toString(), new BeanRowMapper<Card>(Card.class)); // how to mock
        return data;
    }
}
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ CardRepo.class})
class CardTest{
    @Spy
    private CardRepo cardRepository = new CardRepo();
    @Test
    public void getCardList() {         
            Method method = PowerMockito.method(AbstractRepository.class, "getJdbcTemplate");
            PowerMockito.suppress(method);
            Method methodFoo = PowerMockito.method(AbstractRepository.class, "getJdbcTemplate");
            PowerMockito.replace(methodFoo).with(new InvocationHandler() {
                @Override
                public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                    return jdbcTemplate;
                }
            });
            PowerMockito.suppress(MemberMatcher.methodsDeclaredIn(AbstractRepository.class));
            CardRepositoryImpl child = PowerMockito.spy(new CardRepositoryImpl());
            child.getJdbcTemplate();
            PowerMockito.when(child.getJdbcTemplate()).thenReturn(jdbcTemplate);
            List<Card> list = this.cardRepository.getCardList(inputBean);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about this: remove static on the JdbcTemplate, add some setter, remove PowerMock and use Mockito if you want for the JdbcTemplate

Comment: I agree with RC: designs that ask for PowerMock ... very often lack clarity. If you rework your production code, you improve it ... while making it easier to test!